# write to UI in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

This is probably something simple I need to do, I'm trying too access the ui from more than 1 class it works in the mainwindow class but not in the Socket class. I want to write to the display of the ui from the socket class but when I type ui. it should automatically create ui-> and give me a bunch of options.
Here is mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>
#include "studentlist.h"
#include "student.h"

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_buttonGraduate_clicked();
    void on_buttonAverage_clicked();
    void on_buttonDisplay_clicked();
    void on_buttonAddModule_clicked();
    void acceptNewStudent();
    void processFinished(int);

protected:

private:

    QProcess* process;
    StudentList* studentList;

    void displayDetail(QString msg, AbstractStudent* asp);
    int doCheck();
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and socket.h

```
#ifndef SOCKET_H
#define SOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


class Socket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Socket(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
signals:

public slots:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void bytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void readyRead();
private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // SOCKET_H
```

Adding .cpp files

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>
#include "studentserializer.h"
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCloseEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    process = 0;
    studentList = StudentList::getInstance();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete process;
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_buttonAddModule_clicked()
{
    process = new QProcess(this);
    process->start("C:/Unisa/COS3711/Solutions to assignment 2/S2A2Q4ProcessStudent-build-desktop/debug/S2A2Q1GetStudent.exe");
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(acceptNewStudent()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(processFinished(int)));
}

void MainWindow::acceptNewStudent()
{
    QByteArray bytes = process->readAllStandardOutput();
    QStringList items = QString(bytes).split("#");

    QString number = items.at(0);
    QString module = items.at(1);
    int mark = items.at(2).toInt();

    //check if student already exists
    int index = studentList->exists(number);
    if (index == -1) // student does not yet exist
    {
        Student* student = new Student;
        student->setNumber(number);
        student->addModule(module, mark);
        studentList->addStudent(student);

        displayDetail("New student added", student);
    }
    else // student does exist
    {
        AbstractStudent* a = studentList->getStudent(index);
        a->addModule(module, mark);
        displayDetail("Updated student", a);
        a = 0;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonDisplay_clicked()
{
    int index = doCheck();
    if (index >=0)
    {
        AbstractStudent* asp = studentList->getStudent(index);
        displayDetail("Displaying student", asp);
        asp = 0;
    }
}

void MainWindow::displayDetail(QString msg, AbstractStudent* asp)
{
    ui->display->clear();
    ui->display->append(msg);
    ui->display->append("Number: " + asp->getNumber());
    QMap<QString, int> mods = asp->getModules();
    QMapIterator<QString, int> i(mods);
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        i.next();
        ui->display->append("Module: " + i.key() + " Mark: " + QString::number(i.value()));
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonAverage_clicked()
{
    int index = doCheck();
    if (index>=0)
    {
        AbstractStudent* asp = studentList->getStudent(index);
        displayDetail("Displaying student", asp);
        ui->display->append("Module average: " + QString::number(asp->average()));
        asp = 0;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_buttonGraduate_clicked()
{
    int index = doCheck();
    if (index>=0)
    {
        AbstractStudent* asp = studentList->getStudent(index);
        QString msg = asp->graduate()?"This student graduates":"This student does not graduate";
        displayDetail(msg, asp);
        asp = 0;
    }
}

int MainWindow::doCheck()
{
    QMessageBox warning;
    warning.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
    int index=-1;

    if (ui->studentNumber->text().size() == 0)
    {
        warning.setText("Provide a number");
        warning.exec();
        index = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        index = studentList->exists(ui->studentNumber->text());

        if (index == -1)
        {
            warning.setText("Number does not exist");
            warning.exec();
        }
    }
    ui->studentNumber->clear();
    ui->studentNumber->setFocus();
    ui->display->clear();
    return index;
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{
    QFile studentFile("studentlist.xml");
    studentFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream toFile(&studentFile);

    StudentSerializer s;
    QList<AbstractStudent*>* list = studentList->returnList();
    for (int i=0; i<list->size(); i++)
        s.addStudent(list->at(i));
    QDomDocument tempDoc = s.getDoc();
    toFile << tempDoc.toString();
    studentFile.close();

    event->accept();
}

void MainWindow::processFinished(int)
{
    process->close();
    process->deleteLater();
    process=0;
}
```

And socket.cpp

```
#include "socket.h"

Socket::Socket(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Socket::run(){
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)),this,SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));

    qDebug() << "Connecting...";

    socket->connectToHost("twitter.com",80);
    if (!socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {

         qDebug() << "error:" << socket->errorString();
    }
}

void Socket::connected(){
    qDebug() << "Connected";

}

void Socket::disconnected(){
    qDebug() << "Disconected";
}

void Socket::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes){
    qDebug() << "we wrote: " << bytes;
}

void Socket::readyRead(){
    qDebug() << "Reading...";
    socket->readAll();
}
```

those qDebug's I would like to write to the QTextEdit called display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt has the Signal-Slot-Mechanism to do such things!

You shall never access the GUI from worker.

Create a signal within the `Socket` and the appropriate slot within the `QMainWindow`.
Then you can send some `QString`'s to the GUI.

mainwindow.h:

```
public slots:
  void showMessage( const QString& message );

private:
  QLabel* label_; // or something similar
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::showMessage( const QString& message )
{
  // dont forget to create label_ within the ctor
  this->label_->setText(message) // or something similar
}
```

socket.h:

```
signals:
  void sendMessage( const QString& message ) const;
```

socket.cpp:

```
// add or replace the qDebug() part with
emit this->sendMessage("DEBUG MESSAGE");
```

Furthermore, connect `MainWindow` and `Socket` class:

```
QObject::connect(sender*, &Socket::sendMessage, receiver*, &MainWindow::showMessage);
// or Qt 4 style
// QObject::connect(sender*, SIGNAL(sendMessage(QString), receiver*, SLOT(showMessage(QString));
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your socket-class running in a different thread? If so you are not allowed to directly access the ui. If not you must give the socket-class a pointer to the ui, but i do not recommend this.

The prefered solution would be to create a signal in socket-class and connect this to a slot in your mainwindow-class. In this slot do your desired ui-work. In socket-class just emit the signal at the given time, signals can hold data-objects which are sent to the slot.